# what should i use if i want to execute a jframe and a java class simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe, executorservice

I'm creating a java applications and using swings and it have login and logout functionality, when user login successfully then he can check his details which is in another **jframe(login.java)** and can also logout from there.I have also created a java **class(screenshot.java)** which captures screenshots of the desktop at some intervals. Now I want that when user will click login button then both jframe(login.java) which contains user information and java class(screenshots.java) which captures screenshot will invokes simultaneously and while user will check his details then screenshots will also store in some folder simultaneously till user will clicks logout button.I am using **ThreadPoolExecutor** but not succeeded plz help and suggest some ideas..

Comment: Are you asking how to take screen shots while a user enters personal data?

Comment: Please post some of your relevant code here.

Comment: No I want to know that how can I use multiple threads for it

Comment: The answer is, it depends. Do you want the other class to interact with the GUI in anyway? If so, you'll want to explore `SwingWorker`, if not, then a simple `Thread` should do